# Uninstall JDK rpm to reinstall

Tags: centos, fedora, rhel, rpm, jdk

Where do I find the JDK install to uninstall? @terdon had explained using an `rpm` type download so it would be easier to uninstall, but I cannot find it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

#### What's that packages name?

When you don't know the name of a specific RPM to uninstall you can search for it like so using the command `rpm`.

```
$ rpm -aq | grep -i jdk
java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel-1.7.0.60-2.4.4.0.fc19.x86_64
jdk-1.7.0_45-fcs.x86_64
java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.60-2.4.4.0.fc19.x86_64
```

Based on the above output I have 2 versions of Java installed. The official Oracler version, `jdk-1.7.0_45` and the IceTea version aka. Open JDK, `java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.60-2.4.4.0`.

#### Uninstalling

To uninstall the official version of Java (JDK) you could use the following commands, `yum` or `rpm`:

*yum*

```
$ sudo yum remove jdk
[sudo] password for saml: 
Loaded plugins: auto-update-debuginfo, changelog, langpacks, refresh-packagekit
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package jdk.x86_64 2000:1.7.0_45-fcs will be erased
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

=====================================================================================================================
 Package              Arch                    Version                               Repository                  Size
=====================================================================================================================
Removing:
 jdk                  x86_64                  2000:1.7.0_45-fcs                     installed                  193 M

Transaction Summary
=====================================================================================================================
Remove  1 Package

Installed size: 193 M
...
```

*rpm*

```
$ sudo rpm -e jdk
```

I would recommend always trying to use `yum` if you can, it does dependency checks that `rpm` does not.

Comment: I can't wget http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u51-b13/jdk-7u51-linux-i586.rpm

Comment: Yes you have to go in through their website and download the files via your browser. Then use `scp` to copy them to other servers that are headless.

Answer (score 2):

Search pre-installed JAVA:

```
$ rpm -qa | grep java
javapackages-tools-3.4.1-11.el7.noarch
java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.151-5.b12.el7_4.x86_64
```

Remove using following command:

```
rpm -e java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.151-5.b12.el7_4.x86_64
rpm -e javapackages-tools-3.4.1-11.el7.noarch
```

Answer (score 0):

yum remove java

It is working for me

Comment: Removing "java" is broader than removing a single "JDK"...

Answer (score -1):

-> rpm -qa | grep java
java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.312.b02-0.1.ea.el8.x86_64
tzdata-java-2021b-1.el8.noarch
javapackages-filesystem-5.3.0-1.module_el8.0.0+11+5b8c10bd.noarch
java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.312.b02-0.1.ea.el8.x86_64

-> sudo yum remove jna-4.5.1-5.el8.x86_64 java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1:1.8.0.312.b02-0.1.ea.el8.x86_64

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note that [brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Currently, it is extremely difficult to understand how your answer relates to the original problem; please consider expanding it.